# Delete elasticsearch old indices based on created time

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a question regarding **deleting the indices** by date_formant(created date). I am using elasticsearch 6.4

For example, I have a indices structure as below:

```
logstash-2019.03.21
logstash-2019.03.20
logstash-2019.03.15
logstash-2019.03.10
logstash-2019.03.12
```

I want to delete the **indices (not the documents)** let say 3 days older. any help?

NOTE: I have also used different ways, for example.

1. using date math: query {index: '%3Clogstash-%7Bnow-3d%7D%3E'}. this way, it only apply for the single index.

2.

```
let query = {
  index: 'logstash*',
  headers: null,
  body: {
    query: {
      range: {
        '@timestamp': {
          lt: 'now-2d'
        },
      },
    },
  },
};
```

this deletes the documents not the indices.

3. I am not(do not want) using Elasticsearch-curator.

Answer (score 0):

Any reason you don't go for curator? It works nicely to housekeep my cluster.

If you really don't like Curator, shell script might help.

```
#!/bin/bash

curl -XDELETE <YOUR_ELASTICSEARCH_URL>/logstash-$(date -d '-1 day' '+%Y.%m.%d')
curl -XDELETE <YOUR_ELASTICSEARCH_URL>/logstash-$(date -d '-2 day' '+%Y.%m.%d')
curl -XDELETE <YOUR_ELASTICSEARCH_URL>/logstash-$(date -d '-3 day' '+%Y.%m.%d')
```